# AngularJS Form validation transition to valid when some elements are not even touched yet

Tags: javascript, angularjs

[image]

I have a save button that is only enabled when all form data is provided and the form is ***valid***. I don't understand why bandwidth options are not selected and the form become valid. `myForm.$valid` transition to true ... it should stay as `false`

```
<button id="save-create-account-modal" type="submit" class="btn btn-success"
    ng-disabled="!myForm.$valid || $ctrl.disableButton" ng-click="$ctrl.accessPointSave($ctrl.accessPoint)">
    Save
</button>
```

Bandwidth select menu

```
<div class="col-xs-3">
    <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': myForm.uplink.$touched && myForm.uplink.$invalid }">
        <label for="uplink" class="required">
            <translate>GENERAL.UPLINK.value</translate>
        </label>
        <select id="edit-service-plan-uplink-select" class="form-control" name="uplink"
            ng-model="$ctrl.accessPoint.uplink"
            ng-options="bandwidth.value as bandwidth.option for bandwidth in $ctrl.uplinks" required>
        </select>
    </div>

    <span class="message error" ng-messages="myForm.uplink.$error" ng-if="myForm.uplink.$touched">
        <p ng-message="required">
            <translate>GENERAL.FORM_VALIDATIONS.REQUIRED_FIELD.value</translate>
        </p>
    </span>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-3">
    <div class="form-group"
        ng-class="{ 'has-error': myForm.downlink.$touched && myForm.downlink.$invalid }">
        <label for="downlink" class="required">
            <translate>GENERAL.DOWNLINK.value</translate>
        </label>
        <select id="edit-service-plan-downlink-select" class="form-control" name="downlink"
            ng-model="$ctrl.accessPoint.downlink"
            ng-options="bandwidth.value as bandwidth.option for bandwidth in $ctrl.downlinks" required>
        </select>
    </div>

    <span class="message error" ng-messages="myForm.downlink.$error" ng-if="myForm.downlink.$touched">
        <p ng-message="required">
            <translate>GENERAL.FORM_VALIDATIONS.REQUIRED_FIELD.value</translate>
        </p>
    </span>
</div>
```

**How can debug this further?**

---

## Updated

I also tried to add `required` in the same line as my `<select>` tags

> *still not working as expected*

Comment: Does the "None" option in your uplinks and downlinks arrays have a value of `null`? If it doesn't, then AngularJS thinks it satisfies the `required` validation. If it is null, however, then the problem is something else.

Comment: It has value of -1

Comment: It will need to be `null` for the built-in `required` validation to consider it invalid. If that isn't an option, then you will need to make a custom validator that considers -1 to be invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please include a $dirty check as well along with the $valid.

```
($scope.form[field].$dirty && $scope.form[field].$valid){
      //your code
}
```

you can try the ng-required as well.

Answer (score 0):

E.g. this happens when value in select is not one from options.

If you want to debug - required validator is here: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/validators.js